# laravel check between 2 integer from database

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-validation, laravel-query-builder

In database I have simple table as `payment_setting` with some column as `id,min,max,...` now I can use this below code to check between 2 integer:

```
'amount' => 'required|integer|between:1,10'
```

but I want to use `payment_setting` table to check between integers, like with:

```
'amount' => 'required|integer|between:payment_setting.min,payment_setting.max'
```

can I check validation like with that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$ps = DB::table('payment_settings')->where('id', $id)->first();
$rules = [
   'amount' => "required|integer|between:$ps->min,$ps->max"
];
```